# TextWatcher onTextChanged Android Kotlin causes infinite loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 3 fields: fuelAmount, fuelPricePerUnit and fuelCost. I want to add a TextWatcher to every field.
**Logic should look like this:**
`fuelCost` = `fuelAmount` * `fuelPricePerUnit`
`fuelPricePerUnit` = `fuelCost` / `fuelAmount`

```
val refuelTextWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (fuelAmount.text.toString().isNotEmpty() && fuelAmount.text.toString().toFloat() > 0 && fuelPricePerUnit.text.toString().isNotEmpty()
            ) {
                val finalCost =
                    fuelAmount.text.toString().toFloat() * fuelPricePerUnit.text.toString()
                        .toFloat()

                fuelCost.setText(finalCost.toString())
            }
            else {
                /*Toast.makeText(
                    activity,
                    "Error!   ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()*/
            }
        }
    }
    fuelAmount.addTextChangedListener(refuelTextWatcher)
    fuelPricePerUnit.addTextChangedListener(refuelTextWatcher)
```

And it only works for field `fuelCost`. I don't know how to get logic to do `fuelPricePerUnit` = `fuelCost` / `fuelAmount` because I end up with infinite loop or NumberFormatException.
I want to also change value of `fuelPricePerUnit` whenever `fuelAmount` or `fuelCost` change.

Answer (score 0):

`TextView.setText(..)` will trigger the TextWatcher again and again, that's how the loop happens.

Doing for example something like (pseudocode),

```
val cost = fuelCost / fuelAmount
if (fuelPricePerUnit.text != cost)
    fuelPricePerUnit.setText(cost)
```

will most likely get you out of the loop.

Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: i highly doubt that if statement is going to work, there's no way those are the same datatypes

Comment: I stated that's a psaudocode... You can either compare the Float values before converting them to String, or the Strings.